# UITableViewCell with dynamic height make expandable in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

There are the solutions for the fixed row height to expand but I want to expand the cell which is having dynamic height. I am using

```
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

for the row height. Now I want to make these cells expandable Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Ill assume your using AutoLayout if so make the content area on your cell, as in the part that will hold your content eventually after expansion have a fixed height constratint, then when you wanna expand the cell, change the constant to a new value, then call tableView.beginUpdates(), tableView.endUpdates() with no code in between (putting as comment as dont have time to test that will work)

Comment: What would you like to expand the cell for? The answer depends on that really.

Comment: want to add 4 buttons in that expanded area.